# Ionic slider navigation not being properly defined

Tags: typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to add some Ionic Slides navigation to my Ionic project and I found the Ionic Forum thread here https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/navigation-arrows-on-slider/119081/17 and I tried to follow the directions suggested there.

However, I am receiving an error `Cannot read property of 'nextSlide' of undefined`

Obviously I've messed up the declaration in my TS file but I am not sure how. The suggestions on the forum were not specific on how to integrate the logic into the TypeScript file.

Comment: Hey Ryan, this should be easy to fix - can you share your code? specifically ts and html file where your ion-slides are.

Comment: Thanks, I realised it was a simple error that I made when appropriating someone else's code. Answer is below.

Answer (score 0):

Realised I made a simple mistake (apologies for not including code in above question). I referred to my Ionic slider via ID in my TypeScript 'imageSlides':

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams, Slides } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-details',
    templateUrl: 'details.html',
})
export class DetailsPage {
    category: any;
    data: any = {};
    @ViewChild('imageSlides') slides: Slides;

    constructor(
        public navCtrl: NavController,
        public navParams: NavParams
    ) { }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        this.data = this.navParams.get('data');
        this.category = (this.navParams.get('category'));
    }

    goBack(){
        this.navCtrl.pop();
    }

    nextSlide() {
        this.slides.slideNext();
    }

    prevSlide() {
        this.slides.slidePrev();
    }
}
```

But then did not give my slider the ID within my HTML:

```
            <ion-slides pager>
                <ion-slide *ngIf="data.video">
                    <video controls poster="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{data.video}}-poster.jpg">
                        <source src="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{data.video}}.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                    </video>
                </ion-slide>
                <ion-slide *ngFor="let image of data.featured_image">
                    <img src="../../assets/imgs/{{category | slug}}/{{image}}.jpg" class="featured-image"/>
                </ion-slide>
            </ion-slides>
            <button type="submit" float-left ion-button color="primary" class="btnPrev" (click)="prevSlide()">Prev</button>
            <button type="submit" float-right ion-button color="primary" class="btnNext" (click)="nextSlide()">Next</button>
```

Simple fix was to apply the ID to the ion-slides element.